# How can I reset this jquery progress button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, progress-bar

I am using the Custom Progress Control Button (id #controlButton) from the code here: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/10/buttons-built-in-progress-meters/

The button works fine, and shows a progress bar as expected.

I am running `$('#controlButton').progressSet();` at various points in my script to update the progress of the button.

My question is, after the button has been clicked, either before or after the progress bar has finished, how can I reset the button to it's original state, like it hasn't been clicked yet, so that it doesn't say "Done!" or "Loading..."

I have tried removing the `in-progress` and `in-progress:after` classes with

`$('#controlButton').removeClass('in-progress');
$('#controlButton').removeClass('in-progress:after');`

And that stops the progress bar, but the button still says "Loading..."

I'm (obviously) not that experienced with JQuery and JS, so forgive me if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: If you just need to change the text of the button `$('#controlButton').text('Start');`

Comment: have you tried calling `$('#controlButton').progressInitialize();` to re-init it?

Comment: I think you're going to need to do some excavating with that code sample.  There's no such thing as a free lunch!

Comment: Haha, well that's what I've been trying to do---I've tried most of the things suggested here already before asking, in various combinations. But I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with JS and JQuery to fix it. But I'll keep at it... :-)

Comment: Oh, and heres a fiddle that is set up, so others can go to town: https://jsfiddle.net/4evns90h/

Answer (score 0):

try `$("#controlButton").progressFinish().removeClass('finished')` without the `progressSet` method

Comment: This shows the progress bar very briefly, maybe 1/2 second, then goes to "Loading..."

Comment: You would only fire it when you want to show it's fully loaded. I thought that's what you're trying to achieve. Maybe post a fiddle with your code

Comment: If this doesn't work, I think you'll need to modify the progress bar code, to add a new method that does what you want.

Comment: No, @estherz actually what I'm trying to do is completely reset the button, like it has not been clicked, after it has been clicked an my JS code has found form data is invalid. An alert pops up saying "correct so-and-so" and the button should reset to "Start" like it hasn't even been clicked.

Comment: Ah ok I get it (I think) try this ("#controlButton").progressFinish().removeClass('finished')

Comment: Shows progress bar briefly, then goes away, and stays on "Loading..."

Comment: I think something might be initialising your button again. If you run progressStart() the bar starts loading again. I can't tell you more though if I don't see a working code example.

Answer (score 0):

Call `progressFinish` to clear the timer and then reinitialize the progress bar.

```
$("#controlButton").progressFinish().progressInitialize();
```

Comment: I had tried this before. This resets the progress bar, but the text of the button still says "Loading..." instead of "Start" like before it was clicked.

Comment: OK, changed this to combine with the `progressInitialize()` answer.

Comment: Still no dice: now the button says "Loading..." with the progress bar frozen a small ways over.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they are using custom attribute data-loading and data-finished for changing text of that label.

If you are saying you are able to stop loading , you can use

```
 $("#controlButton").text("start");
```

for changing text of the button.

Comment: Doing this flashes "adf" very quickly and then immediately goes back to "Loading...". It doesn't stay with the text set by that. I had tried to do this before with document.getElementById('#controlButton').innerHTML = "Start" and it does the same thing: just quickly flashes "Start" and then goes back to "Loading..."

Comment: That's because the progress bar timer is still running, and it updates the bar based on the current status.

Comment: @ruhnet I just tried.  use .text() method and than remove class 'in-progress'. Works on that demo site